# MaterialDesign-Dialog in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I try to transscript my Android-Application to materialdesign.

I use a NavigationDrawer (with the default AndroidStudio NavigationDrawer-template) and replace the container with a RecyclerView - works all fine.

I definded an FloatingActionButton (FAB) - works.

Now my problem: With i click on the FAB, i want to show an dialog (or something like this) to add new items. As "designguide" for this i use the GoogleCalender-App - "New Event"-Screen here: [image]

I **dont** want to show the NavigationDrawer when i show the "Add Item" screen so i cannot replace the Navigation Drawer container with an Fragment.

Has someone an idea how to handle this? Maybe an (fullscreen) FragmentDialog?

Comment: Why not a new activity?

Comment: I've been thinked about it but was not sure if this is a good solution for this. But it is definitiv an alternative!

Comment: Can you at least tell why you don't think it's a good solution? Because I don't see why an "Add New" routine shouldn't be an activity

Comment: In the GooglCalender-App it is a kind of Dialog. When you use it on a tablet, the layout is not fullscreen. - But that's no obstacle. I have no argument why it should not be an activity, its only an instinct.

Comment: Pedro is right. A new activity sould work just fine. If you want to make it look like a dialog use  Dialog theme

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks. But what is with an "Edit Event"? General: If i dont want to show the NavigationDrawer-flyout or the default Navigation Drawer icon i must everytime use an activiti?